# Can't log into or get Mysql cmd line

Tags: mysql, centos, vps

I have a VPS running CentOS and have apache, php, mysql all installed. I was following a tutorial for installation and apparently did something wrong when setting up mysql (I believe something with setting user and password). Now whenever I try to get to the MySQL command line interface I receive this error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I looked this up and got a few suggestions to try to bypass so I can reset the passwords. I've tried:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

Which came up with the same error. I tried reinstalling by first removing mysql and then installing it again. Same Error appears. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(if U don't have anything in DB, remove mysqlDB - not installation, but DB files in /var/lib/mysql/ - backup it first!)

start this: shell# mysql_secure_installation

it will ask U to:

- Set a root password. If you already have it
- you’ll need to enter it for the remaining steps.
- Remove anonymous users
- Disable non-local root access
- Remove the test database and access rules related to it
- Reload privilege tables so the above changes are in effect

BR